# Is there a limit to how many keys a map can contain in Scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, key

I'm counting the frequencies of certain values belonging to keys ( tags ) in a large XML file ( like for the key "country" how many times the value "USA", "GER", "FRA" etc. occurs ). I do this for all possible keys.

The data structure I use:

```
type IntHash=Map[String,Int]
def IntHash()=Map[String,Int]()

type IntHash2=Map[String,IntHash]
def IntHash2()=Map[String,IntHash]()

var keyfreqs:IntHash2=IntHash2()
```

I update the structure like this:

```
if(current_tag!="name")
{
   var keyfreq=keyfreqs.getOrElse(current_tag,IntHash())                                        
   keyfreq+=(current_value->(keyfreq.getOrElse(current_value,0)+1))
   keyfreqs+=(current_tag->keyfreq)
}
```

All keys can have at most a few thousand different values except for names. There can be hundreds of thousands of different names in the file. As you can see I don't allow possible values for the key "name" to be counted, because if I do, the program stops working ( keys in keyfreqs are lost ).

Is there any limit to how many keys a map can containt in Scala? ( If I allow names, but process only a limited amount of records, the program works. )

Comment: Then I don't understand what's going on because the program never complains about running out of memory. Very strange behaviour: if I run it for 1000 records, everthing is generated as expected. If I run it for 100000 records, all but one keys from keyfreqs disappear ( the content if the remaining one key is correct though ). Here is the whole program: https://github.com/fideplayerslist/fideplayerslist/blob/master/players.scala ( I play around with MAXCNT )

Comment: Your code is too long and have many concerns mixed together. I guess you have a bug there. Try to create a small pice of code that simulates your problem and then we can try to help.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I have this code both in Perl and Python and they both work, so I have experience with this particular structure. I want to learn Scala and chose this problem to implement. I also want to be able to write a GUI app in Scala, this is why the code is so inflated. So far everything went smooth, this is why I'm shocked by such a strange bug. May be later I will return to this problem and try to recreate it in a minimal setup. For now it is more important for me to learn new Scala features and get the whole thing going.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it now.

It is the curse of GUI programming. Processing a large file I want continuous update, so I run the processing in a thread and update in `runLater` blocks. However with a thread you don't notice that the processing has not finished yet and the thread is still running.

In fact I saved the keyfreq records sorted. When the records contained hundreds of thousands of values, the sorting took ages. So only the first key, containing a small number of values was saved, then the program went on sorting the second key, but it never finished. So it looked liked all subsequent keys were missing when I looked at the saved keys.

My mistake was that I took that the saving should take place at an instant. This is because in Python somehow the sorting was faster and I never had to face this delay problem.

May be I don't use the correct method to sort a map by keys:

```
def sortedSerializeIntHash(ih: IntHash): String = {
   val ih_sorted = ListMap(ih.toSeq.sortWith(_._1 < _._1) : _*)

   return serializeIntHash(ih_sorted)
}
```